# How to prevent React Native keyboard from shrinking when TextInput focused?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm really newbie to React Native.

When I focus a `TextInput`, it causes this awful scene:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I use `Flex` and think it's OK.

So can you please tell me where is my problem and what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "KeyboardAvoidingView" from react-native

`import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';`

`<KeyboardAvoidingView> //add form here </KeyboardAvoidingView>`

The below link has a few solutions

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @MihirPanchal I put an image in the question. It causes reformation.

Answer (score 0):

Also add minHeight to the style. so that it won't shrink beyond a limit